# kdb/q: Query multiple handles with hopen

Tags: handle, kdb, q-lang

I would like to be able to query several handles at once, where the tables have the same format like:

handles: 8000,8001,8003
tables: foo

Want to do something like:

```
x:hopen `8000`8001`8003
x select from foo col1,col2
```

So i get rows from each foo table on each handle.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use 'each' to hopen each handle

```
  q)h:hopen each 8000 8001 8002
  q)h
  476 480 484i
```

Use apply each-left to send the same query to each server

```
  q)r:h@\:"select col1,col2 from foo"
  q)r
  +`col1`col2!(1 2;2 3)
  +`col1`col2!(1 2;2 3)
  +`col1`col2!(1 2;2 3)
```

Then you'll have to raze the result:

```
 q)show res:raze r
col1 col2
--------- 
 1    2
 2    3
 1    2
 2    3
 1    2
 2    3
```

Comment: Thanks will try it asap

Comment: Don't forget to `hclose each h`.

Comment: I have a follow up question. How do I do the same  from a remote machine: h:hopen each `:server: 8000 8001 8003                                                                                     
 and then  r: h@\:"select from tbl col1 col2 col3"

Comment: ..And also what if I have handles on server1, server2, and etc what would be the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not planning to reuse the handles, you can do

```
q)raze`::8000`::8001`::8003@\:"select from foo col1,col2"
```

Comment: and can use peach so that requests are sent immediately

Comment: I will probably be reusing them but Thank you Alexander.

Comment: Jack can you please elaborate on the use of peach?

Comment: @AlimHasanov in both answers so far, the result has to come back on port 8000 before the query is sent on port 8001.  That's synchronous communication (aka "get").  It could be done as 3 concurrent "gets" in 3 slaves using [peach](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/peach/).  As well as peach, async ("set") communication can help.

Answer (score 0):

Same as other answers, but more complicated using set (neg h) rather than get (h)

The [cookbook/load-balancing](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/load-balancing/) helps in this example, too.

```
q)h:hopen each 8000 8001 8002
q)h
476 480 484i
q)r:(0#0i)!()               /dictionary of handles and results
```

Set the callback for the response from the servers

```
q).z.ps:{@[`r;.z.w;:;x]}
```

Send a "set" query to each handle

```
q)(neg h)@\:({(neg .z.w)value"select col1,col2 from foo"};`)
```

Wait until all messages have a response

```
q)h .\:()
```

Finally, putting the result together

```
q)raze r h
```

The only advantage is concurrency.

As [@AlexanderBelopolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5403209/alexander-belopolsky) pointed out, don't forget

```
q)hclose each h
```